# Java Script Image sliding

Tags: javascript

I am trying to crete image slide using java script .Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

//variable that will increment through the images
var step = 1
function slideit() {
    var image1 = ["imges/IMG_0579.JPG","imges/IMG_0580.JPG","imges/IMG_0581.JPG"];
    //var image2 = new Image()

    // var image3 = new Image()

    //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
    document.write("hello");

    document.getElementById("slide").src = image1[step];
    document.write("kjds");

    if (step < 3)
        step++;
    else
        step = 1;
    //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
    setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);
}
slideit();
//-->
</script>
```

I am getting console error src is not null

here is img element

```
<img id="slide" src="imges/IMG_0588.JPG" />
```

Comment: create a fiddle... Also, the problem seems to be `document.write`

Comment: Are you sure there is an `img` element with an ID of `slide`?

Comment: yes there is img element with id slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I'm not good at expressing,so I give you the code directly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img  id="slide" src="#" />
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var step = 1
            function slideit() {
            var image1 = ["imges/IMG_0579.JPG","imges/IMG_0580.JPG","imges/IMG_0581.JPG"];
            document.getElementById("slide").src = image1[step];
            if (step < 3)
                step++;
            else
                step = 1;
            //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
            setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);
                }
            slideit();
    </script>
</html>
```